# Allow client to see invoice in UberCart?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

When using Drupal and UberCart, I can view an invoice by going to: admin/store/orders/10006/invoice, but.... clients can't access this, even with the "view own orders" permission.

Is there a way to either give them access to only that link, or an alternative link where they can view it?

Comment: Would like to know this for anonymous users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be able to see it from their user account page. There is a 'My Orders' or 'My Order History' tab that will show previous orders as the invoice.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you visit: `admin/store/settings/orders/edit`

> [ ] checkbox:   Allow customers to view order invoices from their order history.

Answer (score 0):

visitors weren't able to see their own orders. My problem was the permissions (don't know if it was the default settings or I turned it off myself).

Go to: `admin/people/permissions`

and make sure to check:

```
[ ] View own orders
```

for "authenticated user"